# Visual Studio filenotfound: could not load assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I deleted the bin and obj folders in my project and on rebuilding I suddenly got this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Rubix_solver,     Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in     the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'Rubix_solver.dll'
   at     Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference     reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String     fullName)
   at     Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract(DirectoryAssemblyReso    lver res, ICollection`1 jars, ICollection`1 resolvedResourceDirectories,     ICollection`1 resolvedAssetDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedEnvironments)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Execute()
   at     Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecution    Host.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.     <ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()    Rubix_solver.Android
```

I've been trying to fix this issue for about 2 hours now and the only thing I can find on the internet is about fixing your system dll, but I think this dll isn't from my system, but rather generated by visual studio. Can anyone help me fix this error?

Comment: Rubix_solver.dll is not found in your bin directory. you need to put it there.

Comment: But we never used a Rubix_solver.dll and never put it there. This is how our project is called

Comment: check you references. somewhere in your references you have this dll. IF you cannot find inside your references CRTL + F and make advanced search for all your *.cs *.vb files and search for Rubix keyword

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I think this was the problem, I just tried doing that and it suddenly worked. Thank you both. Because of Simonare I knew where to look and Olivier has the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a second project (e.g. a unit test) in the same solution, reference the first project as project reference, not as DLL reference.

This also has the advantage to automatically reference the current Build (Debug or Release).

See also: [Project-to project references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2017#project-to-project-references).

Answer (score 0):

Checkyou references. somewhere in your references you have this DLL.

IF you cannot find it inside your references, CRTL + F and make advanced search for all your *.cs *.vb files and search for Rubix keyword

Hope it helps